# How to get commits via Service Hooks when I merge the pull request?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Azure DevOps Service Hook, here is the service hook detail:
[image]

**My target is get the commits on each code push event.**

When I commit and push the `main` branch directly:
[image]
It works well, but when I commit to another branch, create a pull request, and then merge it into the `main` branch, I cannot get any commits in the code push event payload:

```json
"resource": {
    "refUpdates": [
      {
        "name": "refs/heads/main",
        "oldObjectId": xxx,
        "newObjectId": xxx
      }
    ],
    "repository": {
      "id": xxx,
      "name": "tiny",
      "url": xxx,
      "project": {
        "id": xxx,
        "name": "tiny",
        "url": xxx,
        "state": "wellFormed",
        "visibility": "unchanged",
        "lastUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/main",
      "remoteUrl": xxx
    },
...
```

Get the commits in the code push event if triggered by merge from other branch.